# "I've started my preparation(s) for..." or "I've started preparation(s) for..."?

Tags: pronouns, collocations

Could you tell which of the following sentences sounds the most natural and why?

> I can't go out today. You see, I've just started **my preparation** for the final exam.
>
> I can't go out today. You see, I've just started **my preparations** for the final exam.
>
> I can't go out today. You see, I've just started **preparation** for the final exam.
>
> I can't go out today. You see, I've just started **preparations** for the final exam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They all sound natural, and *could* all mean the same thing. They could also mean slightly different things in context. For example, is it a *student* saying this, or a teacher? If a teacher said "I've started preparations for **the** final exam" that could mean they are preparing to *give* the test, not sit it.

Rather than say "my preparation", why not say "my exam"?

> I can't go out today. You see, I've just started preparing for my final exam.

"Preparation" is also a very broad term that could include packing a bag, getting stationery etc. In British English, students tend to use the term "revision" (verb form: "revising"). I think the US equivalent is just "studying". You might consider saying that you are "revising/studying for my final exam".